# WGET working in WSL shell but not in pythons subprocess

Tags: python, python-requests, subprocess, windows-subsystem-for-linux

**Context**

In a Python (3.11) script in Windows WSL (version 1) I wanted to download a file using the `requests`-module. It didn't work so I did it manually in the shell using `wget`:

`wget https://openaipublic.blob.core.windows.net/encodings/cl100k_base.tiktoken`

Works without any problem, so I thought I'd just wrap it in a subprocess like:

```py
check_output("wget https://openaipublic.blob.core.windows.net/encodings/cl100k_base.tiktoken "), shell=True)

# Alternative
run(["wget", "https://openaipublic.blob.core.windows.net/encodings/cl100k_base.tiktoken"])
```

This fails with the same reason the requests-library failed - It's unable to connect to the source.

**Question**

Besides the obvious thing that the download does not work: I do not understand why I can issue the command in the shell but not via `subprocess` - Shouldn't it just work the same way?
Also assumed Python was using some proxy as I've set the `https_proxy`/`http_proxy` env variables for pip; anyhow, deleting them didn't help as well.

Anybody an idea why this occurs (ultimately leading to hopefully resolve the issue...).

Comment: It should work identically. Maybe there are some changes in the environment. Compare the output of `env | sort` in the shell and within `subprocess.run`.

Comment: Instead of `wget`, run `env -i wget` in both places. They shluld behave identically.

Comment: Hey @pts, thx for your suggestion but the phenomenon does not change... It fails for "Resource temporarily unavailable" when issuing in `subprocess.run` while behaving normal in the shell...

Comment: Please add the output of `ulimit -a` to the question. Maybe you have some low limit set for some resource.

Comment: What is the exact output of the command `python -c 'import subprocess; subprocess.check_call(["wget", "https://openaipublic.blob.core.windows.net/encodings/cl100k_base.tiktoken"])`? What is the exact output of the command `wget https://openaipublic.blob.core.windows.net/encodings/cl100k_base.tiktoken`? What is the output of `type wget`? Please add them all to your question.